# Under what conditions are image files downloaded by chrome tagged with the quarantine attribute?

Tags: macos, security

Seems that if I download a jpeg with Chrome or Firebox it has the quarantine bit set.

Does this mean that OSX has detected something off kilter in this file?

Under what conditions can this be ignored?

Is there a way to turn off the attribute for files downloaded under normal circumstances, but still not leave my self open to other download threats?

Edit:  I've found two places so far that claim that malware can be packaged in an image, and that it can be exploited by a browser.  Apple may have a good idea.

Comment: I believe it's SOP for everything downloaded from the Internet to have the com.apple.quarantine extended attribute set. It doesn't mean it's infected or dangerous. It part of the security measures of the OS.